# prevArrow and nextArrow not working with multiple slick sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow, slick.js

I have multiple sliders on my page and the problem is that the custom arrows I made only work for slider no. 2, e.g. I can press arrows on slider no. 1 or 3, but it will change the pictures on sliders no. 2.

here is the code:

```
**<section id="slideshow">
    <div class="slick">
      <div><img src="pic.jpg" ></div>
      <div><img src="pic2.jpg" ></div>
      <div><img src="pic3.jpg"></div>
    <div>
    <div class="arrow-prev">
       <span><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow-next">
       <span><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></span>
    </div>
</section>**

<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        $('.slick').slick({
            //autoplay: true,
            fade: true,
            dots: false,
            speed: 2000,
            autoplaySpeed: 100,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            arrows: true,
            prevArrow: $('.arrow-prev'),
            nextArrow: $('.arrow-next')
  })
 })
</script>
```

Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's been over a year, BUT I encountered the issues and had to dig really deep to find a good answer.

Since this is the question that popped the most when doing my research

Here it is,

This Solution was suggested by [@Hyzyr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15264945/hyzyr)

It's on this page : [Slick slider appendArrows to multiple containers, arrows not working except last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073085/slick-slider-appendarrows-to-multiple-containers-arrows-not-working-except-last)

> If you are using several slider in one page, you should add additional
> script for this.
>
> ```
> $(window).on("load resize orientationchange", function () {
>     $(".slider").each(function () {
>         var slider = $(this);
>     
>         slider.slick({
>             centerMode: false,
>             centerPadding: '60px',
>             arrows: true,
>             dots: true,
>             slidesToShow: 3,
>             autoplay: true,
>             prevArrow: slider.parent().find('.btnPrev'),
>             nextArrow: slider.parent().find('.slider__btnNext'),
>             
>         });
>     });
> });
> ```
>
> and HTML looks like this
>
> ```
> <div class="sliderParent">
>     <button class="btnPrev"></button>
>     <button class="btnNext"></button>
>     <div class="slider">
>         <div class="item">a</div>
>         <div class="item">b</div>
>         <div class="item">c</div>
>         <div class="item">d</div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```